# Facebook like box border color

Tags: facebook, colors, border

I've got some problem with border-color. I already set up #ffffff. But not working. Where is problem? Facebook make some changes about this?

http://www.raego.cz/ - Mean, lower like-box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, facebook did some changes and the color of the like box is not working anymore for me too. Waiting for someone who knows more than us, at this point!

EDIT: This has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good temporary solution. It works for me.

http://www.zolton.org/2011/04/how-to-hide-facebooks-like-box-border/

I just inlined the CSS like this:

```html
<div style="width:200px;height: 260px;overflow: hidden;position: relative;">
<div style="margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;">
<!-- Your FB plugin -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Facebook just added a new parameter, so instead of using `border_color` and setting its color as your website background color, you should use:

```
show_border=false
```

That's the way you can remove the border..

Answer (score 1):

go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ to make your fb like box again and this time unchecked **Show Border** or add this **data-show-border="false"** to your existed fb like box.

Answer (score 1):

Add data-show-border="false" to the fb-like-box div.

add the following to your css.

```
.fb-like-box { border:solid 1px #444444; }
```

You can also adjust height, width, background, shadowing, border-radius etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You have to set the color hexcode in UPPERCASE:

- #ffffff does not work
- #FFFFFF works OK

It looks really silly, but if fixes the problem with border-color on Facebook Like Box!

Comment: Hex values are meant to be in capitals so #FFFFFF is actually correct. Just thought I would mention that for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

It does work (at least now), but the pound sign needs to be URL encoded.
...`&border_color=%23FFFFFF`...